# How to manage Azure DevOps group permissions with REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to set group permissions by inheriting from another already existing group but it has to be coded. I've managed to create a group but I haven't found a way to edit their permissions, is there any way to do it using either Client libraries or the API resources?

I believe it should be possible to do it using SecurityHttpClient's function SetAccessControlListsAsync() or something similar to it but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: Hi, please show us what have you tried until now

Comment: So far I only managed to create the group like this: ' GraphGroupVstsCreationContext gg = new GraphGroupVstsCreationContext();
            gg.DisplayName = groupname;
            graphClient.CreateGroupAsync(gg);'

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for [Access Control Entries - Set Access Control Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20entries/set%20access%20control%20entries?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) API, which is used to add or update ACEs in the ACL for the provided token.

More details, you can refer to the documentation below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible for the APIs at the moment. I also can not find APIs which are used to set the permission for the group.

@Cece Dong - MSFT, in your response, the API is for security namespace of the organization, but it is not for a group. In another word, I can not find any relationship with the security namespace and group. I created a group in my project, but when i use this API to [query all the security namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/security%20namespaces/query?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0), i can not get the relative group info.